# Downloading Eclipse plug-in update sites for offline installation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

A plug-in that I want to install provides an update site for installation.  However, the Eclipse installation that I want to install it to is on a machine that is not connected to the Internet.  Is there a way for me to access the site (HTTP, FTP, etc.) to download the files in it for offline installation?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Eclipse offers a way of mirroring these sites automatically, either through the command line or through ant tasks.

### Mirror based on p2 information

```
$eclipse_home/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -source $1 -destination $2
$eclipse_home/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source $1 -destination $2
```

Reference: [Equinox p2 repository mirroring](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring)

### Mirror based on site.xml information

```
java -jar $eclipse_home/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar -application org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate -command mirror -from $from -to $to
```

Reference: [Running the update manager from the command line](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html)

You can follow the evolution of these scripts in my [script repository](http://github.com/rombert/scripts/).

Comment: For Kepler use [this](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_mirror.html&resultof=%22mirror%22%20)

Comment: @vincentlcy - isn't that that is found in the 'Mirror based on p2 information' heading?

Comment: oh sorry didnt know it is the same thing. it seems for me in Kepler i cant find this $eclipse_home/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar

Comment: I still have the launcher jar in my Kepler installation, but I think it's optional. So I moved the 'p2' part first, since it's the supported one and looks exactly like the one you linked. Thanks for contributing :-)

Comment: any way to also download the dependencies? coz i've tried doing m2e offline install and it throws an error saying it couldn't find slf4j bundle

Comment: @darthbinamira You should use the b3 Aggregator tool instead to also get all of the necessary dependencies for your plugin(s). See my newly added answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32010272/382885

Comment: @Lucas - yes , from is an update site URL, like http://example.com/update and to is a local filesystem location, like /tmp/eclipse

Comment: Are these methods supposed to work with a site hosted in an ObjectStore type site?  I can't mirror the groovy update site with either of these methods (http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.7)

Comment: Second link ([Running the update manager from the command line](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html)) seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 12):

After struggling with mirroring for some time, I realized that it is much easier (at least, for me) to use "wget" instead.

In short:

1. Download the site:

   `wget --recursive --no-parent http://url.of/updatesite`
2. Take the content of the downloaded update site and move it to your offline environment
3. Add your offline update site directory to the list of available software sites via "Local..." button.

You can read about it with more details [here](http://technotes.khitrenovich.com/how-to-download-eclipse-update-site-for-offline-use/).

Comment: The simpliest method. My main problem was to find an url for Jubula. download.eclipse.org hides content behind "Show Directory Contents" link. Finally i guessed it `http://download.eclipse.org/jubula/release/mars/` .

Comment: This also fails for things that are hosted in S3 or other object store so don't provide a crawlable website.

Comment: Well, it mostly worked 3 years ago. Most of plugins did not use object stores back then...

Comment: wget --recursive --no-parent http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/
but it downloads only the xml file for it. How can I download the full files.

Answer (score 9):

Most Eclipse plug-ins can be installed without the Eclipse updater, by copying the required JARs available at the update site, into the plugins and features directories of the Eclipse installation.

In certain cases, it is necessary to start Eclipse with a -clean switch.

Here's an example of how to do this for the m2eclipse plugin:

1. The m2eclipse update site is http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update. Identifying the list of JARs required is the first step. This is normally found in the site.xml file; in this case, you'll find it in http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/site.xml.
2. Filter the list of JARs to be downloaded to the version of the plugin that you intend to use. This can be determined by the version attribute for each "feature". If you are lucky, you'll find the description of the JAR in the category node.
3. Note the url attribute of each JAR that needs to be downloaded. This will include the subdirectory on the server where the JAR is available, and also the directory in the Eclipse installation where they need to be placed.

PS: This method is a bit hackish, but it is based off the [site-map reference](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_sitemap.html). But do refer to the update

**Update**

I haven't attempted this, but you can create a local mirror site, from where everyone else can pickup the Eclipse plug-ins. In Galileo, this can be done by running the [Eclipse updater in the standalone mode via the mirror command](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html).

Comment: Tried your first suggestion.  Was able to find and download the JARs but they seem to contain nothing.  Installed them in the "dropins" directory and restarted but nothing happened too.  Will try your other suggestion.  BTW, the plug-in I'm trying to install is Mylyn's Generic Web Templates Connector from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/incubator/.

Comment: For the first suggestion, I attempted downloading http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/incubator/features/org.eclipse.mylyn.sandbox.ui_feature_3.2.1.v20090722-0200-e3x.jar. Had no problems downloading it.

Comment: Looking back at it, update URL was http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/incubator and the file mentioned in site.xml was features/org.eclipse.mylyn.sandbox.ui_feature_3.2.1.v20090722-0200-e3x.jar. The effective URL for the JAR is therefore http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/incubator/features/org.eclipse.mylyn.sandbox.ui_feature_3.2.1.v20090722-0200-e3x.jar

Comment: Getting the features won't help. You need the plugins. I suggest trying the Eclipse Updater to create a mirror of the site. Once you do, just package it in a zip and use the zip as an update site from the update manager.

Comment: The same plugins are anyway available from the Mylyn download page as a zip @http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/mylyn/update/mylyn-3.2.1-incubator.zip. That should be easiest way for the OP to distribute the plugins locally.

Answer (score 5):

You can mirror p2 sites using Ant tasks:

```xml
<target name="springide">
    <echo>springide</echo> 
    <p2.mirror verbose="true">
        <repository location="${REPO_HOME}/springide" name="springide" append="true"/>
        <source>
            <repository location="http://springide.org/updatesite" />
        </source>
        <iu id="Core / Spring IDE" version="" />
        <iu id="Extensions / Spring IDE" version="" />
        <iu id="Integrations / Spring IDE" version="" />
        <iu id="Resources / Spring IDE" version="" />
    </p2.mirror>
</target>
```

or findbugs:

```xml
<target name="findbugs">

<echo>findbugs</echo>
    <p2.mirror verbose="true">
        <repository location="${REPO_HOME}/findbugs" name="findbugs" append="true"/>
        <source>
            <repository location="http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/" />
        </source>
        <iu id="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse.feature.group" version="" />
    </p2.mirror>
</target>
```

In order for this to work you have to run ant tasks in the same JVM as eclipse.

You can find IU ID:s by opening "Software Updates" and copy it from there. In Eclipse 3.5 there should be a More... button, in 3.4 you have to click on properties button.

Answer (score 5):

I just faced this issue and resolved it by following the instructions from this [guide](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/07/03/replicating-an-eclipse-update-site-for-offline-usage/). In summary, run the following commands on your terminal in Eclipse folder:

1. `eclipsec.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source $1 -destination $2`
2. `eclipsec.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -source $1 -destination $2`

Where `$1` refers to the URL to the online repository and `$2` refers to the path to the local folder. E.g. to download Vrapper on my Windows Desktop:

$1 = http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/update-site/stable/

$2 = C:/Users/foo/Desktop

Transfer the folder to the machine without Internet connection. Then, launch Eclipse -> Help > Install new software. Specify the local repository (i.e. the folder that you've just transferred) for the installation. That should work.

Comment: Same as existing answer in same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1907322.  Please upvote the existing answer instead and add comments for minor contributions.

Comment: I didn't understand the existing answer when I first read it, that's why I searched for additional information and posted my answer here. The OP of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571201/installing-plugins-for-eclipse-offline also thought that the answer "seems out-dated". But yes, I agree that I should have posted a comment instead, thanks!

Comment: This answer provides much clearer instructions than the accepted answer and is the one I used.  Thanks for providing it.

Comment: The accepted answer on this question is too terse.  This answer told me everything I needed and what each variable was.  I shouldn't have to be an Eclipse developer to understand the answer.  +1

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse plugins usually depend on other plugins. It's kind of hard to trace the dependencies. It's better to download all dependencies using update site once, and you can distribute to other Eclipse dropins. For Eclipse 3.4 or newer, you can use dropins which is an Eclipse feature. This way you don’t have to install plugin from update site every time you have to re-install your Eclipse. Read on http://michsan.web.id/content/how-install-eclipse-plugins-offline

If you can't see the web, I'll give you some description

**Prepare directory for external plugins**

Create special directory to hold our beloved plugins, e.g. in /home/ichsan/eclipse-dropins we will install Maven plugin: m2eclipse.

```
mkdir /home/ichsan/eclipse-dropins
```

For now on, we'll call this directory as DROPINS

**Preparing sandbox**

Next, by using Git we'll create an Eclipse sandbox. The point is to install one plugin on a fresh Eclipse. Instead of installing fresh Eclipse every time we want to install a new plugin, we'd better use Git to create new branch of fresh Eclipse.

First, extract/install new Eclipse to a directory e.g. /home/ichsan/eclipse-sandbox (so that we'll find /home/ichsan/eclipse-sandbox/eclipse.ini). We call the directory as ECLIPSE_SANDBOX.

Next, commit the fresh installation. This step should be done once only.

```
cd $ECLIPSE_SANDBOX
git init
git add .
git commit -am "Fresh Eclipse"
```

**Install plugin on sandbox**

Now is the interesting part. Supposed we have to install m2eclipse plugin. We will install this on new Git branch so that the master branch will stay clean or stay intact.

```
cd $ECLIPSE_SANDBOX
git checkout -b "m2eclipse"
```

Now, we start the Eclipse of the ECLIPSE_SANDBOX and download the plugin. Once we're done, we shut the Eclipse down and check what new directories or files have been created (using Git). Remember that, we only care about new plugins and features directories and the contents inside them. So, we won't copy the rest into dropins.

```
# Prepare the m2eclipse plugin directories
mkdir -p $DROPINS/m2eclipse/eclipse/plugins
mkdir -p $DROPINS/m2eclipse/eclipse/features

cd $ECLIPSE_SANDBOX
for f in $(git status | sed "s/#\t//g" | grep -P "^plugins" ); do cp -R $f $DROPINS/m2eclipse/eclipse/plugins; done
for f in $(git status | sed "s/#\t//g" | grep -P "^features"); do cp -R $f $DROPINS/m2eclipse/eclipse/features; done

# Make the directory read only
chmod -R -w $DROPINS/m2eclipse

# Commit changes
git add .
git add -u
git commit -am "M2Eclipse plugin installed"


# Back to master branch to make Eclipse clean again and ready for other plugin installations
git checkout master
Installing the plugin
```

Just copy the directory of DROPINS/m2eclipse into ECLIPSE_HOME/dropins or create a symbolic link. And we're done!

```
cd $ECLIPSE_HOME/dropins ln -s $DROPINS/m2eclipse
```

Another way is to backup differences between fresh-Eclipse commit and after-plugin-installation commit.

```
for i in `git diff hashFreshEclipse hashPluginInstall --name-only`;do 
  if [ -f $i ]; then
    tar -r -f m2e-android.tar $i
  fi
done
gzip m2e-android.tar
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from here https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e/1.3.0/N/1.3.0.20121023-1108/

Download all files drilling down into plugins and features.  Store in a directory on your machine keeping everything in the same directory structure.  Move it to a folder on your dev machine.

In Eclipse go to Help | Intall New Software...
Hit the 'Add' button
Hit the 'Local...' button
Browse for the directory you dropped the files into.  Follow the on screen instructions.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the p2 mirrorApplication did not work very well on some sites and mirrored duplicate artifacts (both the pack200 and jar version). The b3 Aggregator worked much better and made it much easier to customize my update site. See the manual at: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_b3/aggregator/manual for install instructions and details.

The basic steps I used were:

- File > New > Other... > b3 > Repository Aggregation.
- Select the **Aggregation** node and set the *Build Root* to the folder where you want the aggregated repo to go.
- Add the platforms you care about using R-click the **Aggregation** node > New Child > Configuration.
- Add one **Validation Set**, normally set its *Label* to main.
- If you don't need any additional bundles from the main eclipse repository (ie: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars), you can add it to the **Validation Set** as a **Validation Repository**, but typically you will need to add it as a **Mapped Repository** under a **Contribution** so dependencies and/or additional eclipse features can be downloaded.
- For each plugin, add a **Contribution** with a *Label*, and under that at least one **Mapped Repository** with a *Location*.
- Add **Custom Category** nodes to the **Aggregation** if you want; give them each a unique *Description*, *Identifier*, and *Label*.
- Expand the **Repository Browser** node at the bottom > expand the repo url > expand the **Installable Units** > Look at the features under **Categories** (if present) and/or under **Features**.
- R-click the features you want and Add to Custom Category (if you are using those), otherwise Add to parent mapped repository as > Mapped Feature.
- R-click any node > Build Aggregation.

**Important Note:** if you don't map any features from a given repository, that entire repository will be mirrored (the latest versions of all bundles I think, not actually everything in the repo).

I fortunately didn't have to mess with Exclusion Rules or Valid Configuration Rules, which seem to make things more complicated. However, exclusion rules may be necessary if the repositories contain bundles that have dependency conflicts, in which case one or more conflicting bundles need to be excluded.

While b3 Aggregator normally only downloads the latest version of every feature you have mapped (and it's dependencies), if you repeatedly use *Build Aggregation* over time as new versions are released, the obsolete versions will accumulate in your aggregation. You could use *Clean then Build Aggregation* but this means you will have to redownload everything. Instead, simply add another .b3aggr aggregation file, set the Build Root, add your Configurations, and add one Contribution with a Mapped Repository using the path to your local mirror's `final` directory. Don't map any features or create any categories. Then Build Aggregation and only the latest versions from your mirror will be aggregated!