# Is there a way to extract an eclipse plug-in from a PC and install on an offline Linux system?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, extract, helios

I have a 64-bit Fedora 13 computer running Eclipse Helios that doesn't have access to the Internet and I would like to install the CUTE plug-in.

I have been able to install the plug-in on my Windows XP computer that is connected to the Internet and I was wondering if there is a way to extract the plug-in from my PC, bundle it (probably with WinZip) and install it on my Fedora box.

I've tried several different searches on Google and Bing but can't seem to get the words in the correct order to find the answer.  I've also tried to get onto the Eclipse forums but they are having problems with people trying to login from networks that use caching proxies so I haven't had any luck there either.

-edit-
I was finally able to get on the Eclipse forums and have asked the same question and will share any results I find here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that. There is more to installation of plugins than moving the jars.

What you need is a zipped repository of CUTE. The same thing that's published on their web site, but in zipped form to be used in offline mode. A quick browse of CUTE website doesn't show that they publish this. I recommend asking on their support forum to provide a zipped repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't obtain a zipped repository because they only offer an update site, you could mirror the update site using the b3 Aggregator. See my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010272/382885