# is it possible to download an eclipse plugin repository?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

i've got a PC with no internet connection and i need to install certain Eclipse plugins. is there a way to download the whole repository the plugins reside in (so that i can transfer it as a zip to my offline PC and point the Eclipse Updater to a local plugin repository)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the p2 mirror task (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Ant_Tasks#Mirror_Task) or the B3 Aggregator (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_b3/aggregator/manual).

Comment: yes, me stupid, it seems there's an answer for that already:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation