# Installing CUTE plugin offline

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, offline

I need to install CUTE plugin to a Eclipse in a computer which is not connected to internet. Can someone please tell me where I can find zip file of CUTE plugin.

Searching internet only gave me "http://www.cute-test.com/updatesite", which only allows me to install the plugin through internet..

Comment: As of my knowledge there is no zip file available for this, you have to install from updatesite only.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this question on how to create a local copy of the update site: [Downloading Eclipse plug-in update sites for offline installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation).