# How can I offline install eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How can I know and download all plugin dependencies so that I could install it later offline

without the need of internet

Thanks

Comment: You can mirror update sites for later use, see this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation/1907322#1907322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [p2 mirror](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_mirror.html&cp=2_0_20_3_0) facility to create a local copy of the p2 repos you need.  Then you can install it later off line.

I use ant mirror scripts to mirror p2 repos (ex: [mirror-jface.xml](http://git.eclipse.org/c/e4/org.eclipse.e4.releng.git/tree/org.eclipse.e4.builder/builder/general/mirror-jface.xml)), and they can be run like:

```
bash$ eclipse/eclipse -noSplash \
-application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner \
-DbaseDir=/some/useful/basedir -buildfile mirror-jface.xml
```

You have to specify all of the repositories to search in order to pick up all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you start off by installing the plugin online, then open up the folowing view:

```
Window->Show View->Other->Plug-in Development->Plug-in Registry
```

In that view find the plugin(s) you're interested in, expand them, and make a note of all the pluigns under the "Prerequisites" section. Note that it only lists direct dependencies, so you may need to follow these down to find the whole dependency hierarchy.

Quite a manual process, and hopefully someone else can point out an easier way, but this should give you a full list of plugins that you can then install offline.