# Creating a custom Eclipse installation?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I have a number of tools that I typically install with Eclipse, such as Subversive, PMD, EclEmma, etc. Every time I update Eclipse, I have to manually go through and add each of the tools as well. Is there a way to package the tools so I can install them together rather than individually?

Answer (score 2):

I know of two possible solutions - none of them exactly what you ask for, but...

- Use the Export wizard "Install" -> "Installed Software Items to File" to create a descriptive file with the features and update site you use. You get to choose which features to include. Also note that the generated `p2f` file does not include the binary features and plug-ins themselves - just a descriptive reference. (I should say, that I have had some problems with the corresponding import wizard, but YMMV...)
- Alternatively, you can use the import wizard "Install" -> "From Existing Installation" to install features from an *old(er)* Eclipse installation into the *new(er)* Eclipse installation. It is a one time operation, and you can then update the installed features the usual way via the appropriate update sites (these are usually installed automaticaly).

Personally, I use the second method, as I then don't have to keep updating the `p2f` file whenever I find some new interesting features and - as noted above - the import wizard doesn't always work as I would expect.

I keep the old Eclipse installation around for some time anyway to ensure I have something to fall back on in case of problems...

Comment: I like this, I'll probably give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to me is downloading every plugin you need. Store it in a folder and in the Eclipse Update dialog, select that folder in place of the URL.

Cannot remember if you also need to compile some sort of XML list of plugins installed.

With this setup, each time you install Eclipse, simply you use its update procedure and install every package you find using as Update Url your directory.

PS: Take a good look at this [excellent question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation?rq=1)