# Download Eclipse plugin without manager

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How to manually download (via browser) eclipse plugin as jar or zip without eclipse plugin manager, so you can save it for latter?

How to get link of file from update site link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some update sites offer a zip file aswell that you can download, unzip and install offline, buf I feel that is quite rare.

What you want to do is to mirror the update site to your harddrive. There is a built in feature for that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation/1907322#1907322) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find plugins in [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.com), and for manually installing part please have a look at [dropins](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins)