# How to install eclipse color theme plugin offline?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My computer hasn't internet connection at work. How I can install eclipse color theme plugin offline?

http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin

P.S. I use eclipse 4.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading Eclipse plug-in update sites for offline installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation)

Answer (score 4):

From the downloaded zip file, extract and place the jar files into their respective folders i.e. in `plugins` and `features`.

Now, start the eclipse application and go to **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **General** -> **Appearance** -> **Color Theme** and choose the theme from the list.