# Downloading Eclipse plug-in from Eclipse Marketplace for offline usage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

A plug-in that I want to install (Eclipse Jubula Database Drivers) is only available in Eclipse Marketplace. However, I need to install it to an Eclipse package running in a machine that is not connected to the Internet. Is any way to get the update site address so I can download the files for offline installation? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation) solves the problem to download an update site, but I don't see a way to get the update site address from eclipse marketplace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On every plugin page of Eclipse Marketplace, use the rightmost icon underneath the "Install" button. That opens an overlay containing the URL of the update site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. After spending a couple of weeks, I found this simple process:

1. Unpack Eclipse in folder `A`
2. Unpack Eclipse in folder `B`
3. Start Eclipse in folder `A`
4. Install the plug-in
5. Delete all files in the folder `plugins/` which are the same in both Eclipse installs.
6. Delete all files in the folder `features/` which are the same in both Eclipse installs.

That leaves you with the files necessary to run the plugin. But since this isn't an update site anymore, you can't easily install the plugin.

To solve this problem, you have two options:

1. Put the files into the [`dropins/` folder](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html)
2. Create an update site using the files which you identified. Good luck with that. I tried it for months but the result was unstable at best ("Component can't be installed because ...").

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up on Aaron's answer, the relevant files from `plugins/` and `features/` go into a new folder `eclipse/` which can then be put into the `dropins/` folder.

So for a concrete example, I wanted to install the [Jenerate plugin](https://github.com/maximeAudrain/jenerate) to an offline machine. At the time I tried this, the update site was offline. So I went ahead and installed it via Marketplace on another machine with internet access, which lead to the creation of a folder `features/org.jenerate.feature_1.0.2` as well as a jar `plugins/org.jenerate_1.0.2.jar`. I put those into newly created directories on the offline machine in `dropins/jenerate/eclipse/features` and `dropins/jenerate/eclipse/plugins`, respectively. See also this [Eclipse help document](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html).