# How can I download the Eclipse CVS plugin for the Eclipse 20221-09 separate from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cvs, eclipse-2021-09

I need to add the CVS plugin to a Eclipse install which sits on a machine without Internet access. For this I want to download the CVS plugin on another machine just as a zip file.

But I was not able to find a URL from which I can separately download the CVS plugin for the current Eclipse version Eclipse 2021-09.

---

*Please note:* I saw older posts about this topic like "[Install the Eclipse CVS plugin without Internet access - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821351/install-the-eclipse-cvs-plugin-without-internet-access)" but all their actual URL information is outdated and I couldn't deduct a current URL for the CVS zip file from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you can see the actual plug-in directly under the 2021-09 download directory, but you can grab the jar from https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000/plugins/org.eclipse.cvs_1.4.1900.v20210906-0500.jar and add it to the `dropins` folder of your installation.

Comment: Thanks. The download works. The jar is probably all I need. Will test it out with Eclipse. Thanks again.