# Gradle - How to download buildship outside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I am trying to install the buildship plugin into Eclipse. As the Eclipse is installed in client's virtual box and has some limitations, the tool is not able to connect to Internet to install the buildship plugin. Even after configuring the proxy settings in Eclipse, its not connecting to Internet.

In order to overcome this issue, I am trying to download the buildship plugin locally and then refer it in Eclipse. But the buildship plugin website does not have a feature to download it standalone.

FYI, I was able to install the plugin in Eclipse in my local machine where there is no issue in connecting with internet.

Answer (score 0):

Your'question is about how do to do an offline installation of eclipse plugins?

Use one of the many solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation) to mirror a plugin repo you're interested in. Copy the mirror to the network limited machine, and add the repo directory to eclipse list of update repos via the `local` button.

You can also copy over your local eclipse directories after you've installed the required plugins.

Comment: There are also detailed instructions specifically for this plugin in their github page: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/