# How to install groovy plugin for eclipse without using the update site link

Tags: eclipse, gradle, groovy, eclipse-plugin

Because of the firewall issue in the company, I cannot install the groovy plugin with the update site link provided [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki), is there any workaround for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can try some of the answers listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download an offline eclipse update-site in the CI server, [here](https://build.spring.io/browse/GRECLIPSE)

Comment: I spent all afternoon on failed attempts to mirror this update site before I came upon this answer.  Thank you.