# Installing plugins for Eclipse offline

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin, efxclipse

I want to install e(fx)clipse for Eclipse Neon, however eclipse is running on a machine that does not have internet access. Is there a way I can manually download a plugin and install it to eclipse?

To clarify: I have access to the internet on another machine that I can use to transfer files onto the machine with Eclipse.

Comment: These scripts mirror a repository into another one, which can be a local one. Some projects also offer to download a zipped version of their online repo. See the download instructions of theroject I question if this is the case.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Ok, I've never seen these types of scripts before so Ill see if I can figure it out. I am trying to get JavaFx if that helps

Comment: JavaFX is part of the JRE, did you mean e(fx)clipse?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann yes, sorry. e(fx)clipse is what i am trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can download the update-site as a zip by modifying the update site adress last part by site_assembly.zip

example : Install URL becomes,

```
http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/2.4.0/pluginName
http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/2.4.0/pluginName_assembly.zip
```

*change version number if you need an other one*

and then use this zip to install your plug-in (**Help > Install New Software > Add**) as you do but instead of adding an update site url select zip and give the zip you download see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074606/3501345) part 2 for screenshot :