# Manual install of Groovy-Eclipse feature to STS 3.7.3

Tags: groovy, spring-tool-suite, groovy-eclipse

I'm learning Spring Boot using STS and working through a tutorial. One of the exercises in the tutorial demonstrates the inclusion of a .groovy controller. For it to run, I need to install the Groovy-Eclipse feature and, because I'm behind a firewall, I have to download the update site as a zip and install from local. The question is - which version of Groovy-Eclipse do I need for STS 3.7.3, and where can I download the zipped archive from?

Thanks in advance

Angus

Answer (score 2):

STS 3.7.3 is based in Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) (https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/01/spring-tool-suite-3-7-3-released).

The Groovy-Eclipse update sites for every Eclipse version are listed here: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki.

For howto download an Eclipse update site see: [Downloading Eclipse plug-in update sites for offline installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation).

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to STS-> Help -> Install new Software -> add the below URL
http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/

try with : http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/ instead of https://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/

Ref for Use one of the following update sites depending on your version of Eclipse: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/3.5.0-Release-Notes 

https is giving the error like "Unable to read repository at https://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/content.xml.
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
```