# Installing Scala Maven plugin on eclipse from local

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, eclipse-plugin, scala-maven-plugin

I am trying to setup Scala development environment with maven on scala IDE for eclipse. I am not able to install the Scala Maven plugin from the software site due to some problems with my proxy settings. So, I am trying to download the plugin onto my local system and then install it.

I got the Scala Maven plugin from this site: 
https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin

I've unzipped the plugin and tried to install it from eclipse using 'install new software' but eclipse gives errors like this:

```
Could not find file: C:\..\..
```

This may be dumb, but I need help! What is the right way to install the plugin?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The scala-maven-plugin is a maven plugin, not an eclipse plugin.  Are you sure you need to install this manually?  Just adding the definition to your pom.xml should be enough.

Comment: I am trying to create a new maven project with the scala archetype. I can't find the scala archetype option in the list. So, I thought I need to install this Scala Maven plugin. Not sure if I am right.

Answer (score 0):

`scala-maven-plugin` is a maven plugin, to install it, juste declare it in your pom.xml (already done with the the archetype) like in the [doc](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/usage.html)

For eclipse, you need the following plugins:

- [scala-ide](http://scala-ide.org/) to add support of scala into eclipse, could be installed from eclipse's marketplace (iirc)
- [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) to add support of maven into eclipse, cloud be installed from eclipse's marketplace (iirc)
- [m2eclipse-scala](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-scala) to add link between scala-ide, m2e, eclipse and maven-scala-plugin

See http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've downloaded the m2eclipse-scala plugin from the link you provided. Can you please explain how can I install the plugin from local? thanks!

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu, you can try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation